# Change cell reference when adding a new row in base sheet

Tags: excel, reference, row, formula

I have 2 excel files: base sheet in the 1.xlsx with raw data and formula sheet for formulas in 2.xlsx

base file 1.xlsx:  
1 - 1  
2 - 2  
3 - 3  
4 - 4  
5 - 5

formula sheet in 2.xlsx  
1 - ='basesheet'!A1  
2 - ='basesheet'!A2  
3 - ='basesheet'!A3  
4 - ='basesheet'!A4  
5 - ='basesheet'!A5

Then I insert a new row in the base sheet 1.xlsx:  
1 -   
2 - 1  
3 - 2  
4 - 3  
5 - 4  
6 - 5

I want my cell references in the formula sheet in 2.xlsx updated, so I have  
1 - ='basesheet'!A2  
2 - ='basesheet'!A3  
3 - ='basesheet'!A4  
4 - ='basesheet'!A5  
5 - ='basesheet'!A6

is it possible and how can I do that?

P.S. Data is very large, this is just a simple case

Comment: As far as I know, this is the default behavior of Excel. You just insert the new row and things are done. Just try and share the result with us.

Answer (score 1):

**This already is an inbuilt feature in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel)**

[image]

---

EDIT: This applies not only to `Worksheets` but also to 
`Workbooks`:

[image]

Comment: Please read the question carefully. The raw data and formulas are in different sheets!!!

Comment: You haven't watched the gif carefully. There are different sheets in my answer as well

Comment: Try `Formulas -> Calculation Options -> Automatic`, but I doubt it should affect it

Comment: Sorry, I formulated my question in a wrong way. These 2 sheets are in different files, not in the same file.

Comment: Still displays the same behaviour

Comment: my office version is 2010, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @GorLazyan Perhaps. I don't have older versions installed so I can't test

Comment: Maybe I got the idea. While all the files are open, everything works. But when you open only raw data file, make changes and then open the formula file, they are updated!